# Azure active directory graph api query user

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am working on an app that needs to query Azure AD. The query is working on some fields but on some fields like mobile number it's not working.

Query is working when filtering with name

```
var searchResults = await userCollection.Where(user =>
                (user.UserPrincipalName.StartsWith(searchString) ||
                user.DisplayName.StartsWith(searchString) ||
                user.GivenName.StartsWith(searchString) ||
                user.Surname.StartsWith(searchString) ||
                user.Mail.StartsWith(searchString)) && user.AccountEnabled == true).ExecuteAsync();
```

but with mobile number and other fields it throws exception

```
var searchResults = await userCollection
                .Where(x => x.Mobile == "+63 922 3965 021").ExecuteAsync();
```

Here is the exception 
"Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property 'mobile' of resource 'User'."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some properties that you can query that way. The Linq query generates a `Filter` expression towards the [Azure AD Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api). But others, like the mobile number, you can't.

The properties that are filterable can be seen [in the reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity) for user objects.

The ones that you can filter on are marked as such (e.g. the `Surname` property: "GET ($filter)").

Comment: it doesn't make sense why it cant' be query

Comment: I know. I've wanted it as well. You can add a UserVoice request at https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/category/165567-graph-api. BTW. the newer Microsoft Graph API doesn't support filtering on mobilePhone either (its reference is at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user#properties).

Comment: Is there good C# example programs available to demonstrate use of the `MS Graph` APIs for the entity `User` ? such a pain to find them. The graph api nuget v5 [page](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/feature/5.0/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#query-options) has few examples, but not fully helpful!